# Views Field Show "NEW" if less than 1 day old

Tags: views

I am displaying webform submissions in a view, and need to add a "NEW" notification if the submission is less than a day old.

I have created views-view-field--myfield.tpl.php and have managed to change the value of my field using the template.

I am grabbing the submitted date, which I have printed already to make sure it works, and it comes up as `13/05/2014 - 23:13`

I am then trying to figure out how to return a value for a date that is less than 1 day old. I'm pretty sure the following should do it, but it always renders "not new".

```
<?php
$submitted = $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields[$view->row_index]['submitted'];

if( $submitted > strtotime('-1 day') ) {
  echo '<div style="color:red;">NEW!</div>';
}
  else
{
  echo 'not new';
}
 ?>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

So, this works...

```
if( strtotime('14 May 2014') > strtotime('-1 day')) {
  echo '<div style="color:red;">NEW!</div>';
}
else
{
echo 'nothing <br />';
}
```

If i set it to 14th may (today) Its shows up as NEW! , any earlier, it prints nothing.

So, this leads me to believe there is a problem with my submitted date.

But, If I put `echo $submitted;` i get `13/05/2014 - 23:13`

If I put `$newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($submitted)); echo $newDate;` i get `01 Jan 1970` for every result.

And If I put `$newDate = date("d M Y", $submitted); echo $newDate;` I also get `01 Jan 1970` for every result.

So now I don't know what's going on. If its not in timestamp format, strtotime should sort it shouldnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need to strip the html from `$submitted` and convert to timestamp first, 
e.g something like:

```
$submitted = $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields[$view->row_index]['submitted'];

if (strtotime(strip_tags($submitted)) > strtotime('-1 day')) {
  echo '<div style="color:red;">NEW!</div>';
}
```

Comment: hmm. Nope not working either. I dont actually get any results when I echo strip_tags($submitted); , only when i echo $submitted.

Comment: `strip_tags($submitted);` only strips html, the submitted text value should still be there - what value do you get for `$submitted`?

Comment: echo $submitted; returns 13/05/2014 - 23:13

Comment: I tried printing todays date and the exact same format, and doing a subtraction to get the difference, and then doing $difference / 84600 to get the days, but the result is always 0.

Comment: `echo strip_tags('13/05/2014 - 23:13');` returns `13/05/2014 - 23:13` you need to convert the value to a unix timestamp with strtotime to compare, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried that, but im getting the results in my updated question.